# Plot a conditional grouped bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hello to all I am trying to plot a grouped bar chart so in the x axis is the month, y axis is the unique number days by id and the grouped bars are: the id with age under 35 and the other is the ids equal or higher than 35 age. Could anyone help? Thank you.

This is how I found the average of days per month for those under 35. I can always calculate the same for those equal or older than 35 but I can plot a barchart with those 2 groups per month.

```
df <- subset(xxx,xxx$age<35)

df %>%
  mutate(month = months(date)) %>% #get month
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = n_distinct(date)) %>% #by user and month find range
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Days = mean(xx1)) #average ranges by month
```

My data:

```
structure(list(id = c("f1", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f6", "f1", "f5", "f3", 
"f2", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f2"), age = c(37L, 34L, 36L, 34L, 
54L, 38L, 46L, 34L, 42L, 38L, 38L, 42L, 42L, 53L, 31L),date = structure(c(18687, 
18682, 18683, 18685, 18687, 18683, 18687, 18683, 18687, 18687, 
18687, 18687, 18687, 18683, 18684), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what your intended outcome is; please advise whether this plot is approximately what you're after, and/or what changes you would like to make:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(id = c("f1", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f6", "f1", "f5", 
                            "f3", "f2", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f2"),
                     age = c(37L, 34L, 36L, 34L, 54L, 38L, 46L, 34L,
                             42L, 38L, 38L, 42L, 42L, 53L, 31L),
                     date = structure(c(18687, 18682, 18683, 18685, 18687,
                                        18683, 18687, 18683, 18687, 18687,
                                        18687, 18687, 18687, 18683, 18686),
                                      class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 15L),
                class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  mutate(month = months(date),
         `Age Group` = if_else(age <= 35, "35 or under", "Over 35")) %>%
  group_by(month, `Age Group`) %>%
  mutate(`Unique days per month` = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = `Unique days per month`, fill = `Age Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Sorry I misunderstood your question - it was explained well, I just didn't get it - thanks for clarifying. Here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(id = c("f1", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f6", "f1", "f5", 
                            "f3", "f2", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f3", "f4", "f2"),
                     age = c(37L, 34L, 36L, 34L, 54L, 38L, 46L, 34L,
                             42L, 38L, 38L, 42L, 42L, 53L, 31L),
                     date = structure(c(18687, 18682, 18683, 18685, 18687,
                                        18683, 18687, 18683, 18687, 18687,
                                        18687, 18687, 18687, 18683, 18686),
                                      class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 15L),
                class = "data.frame")

# Avg_Days for patients under 35
df2 <- subset(df, df$age<35)
df2 %>%
  mutate(month = months(date)) %>% #get month
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = n_distinct(date)) %>% #by user and month find range
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Days = mean(xx1))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   month    Avg_Days
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 February      1.5

# Avg_Days for patients over 35
df3 <- subset(df, df$age>35)
df3 %>%
  mutate(month = months(date)) %>% #get month
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = n_distinct(date)) %>% #by user and month find range
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Days = mean(xx1))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   month    Avg_Days
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 February        1
#> 2 March           1

# Avg_Days plotted for both Age Groups
df %>%
  mutate(month = months(date),
         `Age Group` = if_else(age <= 35, "35 or under", "Over 35")) %>%
  group_by(id, month, `Age Group`) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = n_distinct(date)) %>%
  group_by(month, `Age Group`) %>%
  mutate(`Mean unique days per month` = mean(xx1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = `Mean unique days per month`, fill = `Age Group`)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is the layout i wanted but i would like to demonstrate the average of days in each month, not the total distinct days. In my sample code i provided above i calculate the distinct dates grouped by month and id and the then i find their average. So this is what i am trying to demonstrate in the graph, the average days per month for the two age groups

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I have edited my answer to suit. Please let me know if this does/doesn't solve your problem.